# Discord.js V11 System Stats Command

Tags: discord

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
var osu = require('node-os-utils')
var cpu = osu.cpu
var drive = osu.drive
var mem = osu.mem
var netstat = osu.netstat


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {var count = cpu.count()
cpu.usage()
  .then(cpuPercentage => {
    console.log(cpuPercentage)
  })
drive.info()
  .then(dinfo => {
    console.log(dinfo)
  })
mem.info()
  .then(minfo => {
    console.log(minfo)
  })

netstat.stats()
  .then(ninfo => {
    console.log(ninfo)
  })

  let systemEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor("RANDOM")
  .setTitle("Urban Bot System Stats")
  .addField("CPU Cores", count, true)
  .addField("CPU Usage", osu.cpu, true)
  .addField("Drive Usage", osu.drive, true)
  .addField("Memory Usage", osu.mem, true)
  .addField("Network Stats", osu.netstat, true)
  .addField("Logged In User", "Administrator", true)
  .addField("Operating System", "Windows Server 2016 Standard", true)

  message.channel.send(systemEmbed)
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "system"
}
```

[What the Embed Appears Like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKRur.png)

I am trying to do a command that shows system stats. However once it is run on all of the fields it displays "object Object" could anyone help?

Please see the embed for more on what it looks like. It is in a file called `system.js` in the command handler. The main entry is `index.js`.

Comment: So all parameters are object. Like  `osu.mem` has property `max` and ` current`. Try console.log it to get property whats you need